# Multiple windows open at once in python

Tags: python, user-interface, python-3.x, tkinter, python-3.4

I've searched and found a few things on parent windows in python but that is not what I was looking for. I am trying make a simple program that opens a window and another window after that when the previous one is closed. I was also trying to implement some kind of loop or sleep time to destroy the window by default if the user does not. This is what I have (I'm new please don't laugh)

```
 from tkinter import *
 import time
 root = Tk()


 i = 0

 if i < 1:
     root.title("title")
     logo = PhotoImage(file="burger.gif")
     w1 = Label(root, image=logo).pack()
     time.sleep(3)
     root.destroy()
     i = i + 1


 if i == 1:
     root.title("title")
     photoTwo = PhotoImage(file="freedom.gif")
     labelTwo = Label(root, image=photoTwo).pack()
     time.sleep(3)
     root.destroy()
     i = i + 1





 mainloop.()
```

Comment: What's your question? What do you need help with?

Comment: Use one root window and put the contents on two frames.  Pack frame1, later unpack it (frame1.pack_forget or frame1.destroy) and pack frame2.  Change root.title and other attributes if you want.

Comment: Also, never (almost) use time.sleep with tk (or other asynchronous event framework).  Use root.after instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you're looking for something like this:

```
from tkinter import *
import time




def openNewWindow():
    firstWindow.destroy()


    secondWindow = Tk()
    secondWindow.title("Second Window")

    photoTwo = PhotoImage(file="freedom.gif")
    labelTwo = Label(secondWindow, image=photoTwo).pack()

    secondWindow.mainloop()



firstWindow = Tk()


firstWindow.title("First Window")

logo = PhotoImage(file="burger.gif")
w1 = Label(firstWindow, image=logo).pack()

closeBttn = Button(firstWindow, text="Close!", command=openNewWindow)
closeBttn.pack()

firstWindow.mainloop()
```

This creates a button in the first window, which the user clicks. This then calls the openNewWindow function, which destroys that window, and opens the second window. I'm not sure there's a way to do this using the window exit button.

Comment: It did open 2 windows... One with the first image and the other blank. When the button is clicked it packs the second image into the first window :/

Comment: @Bill Edited, I forgot to change the window the photo should be in.

Comment: It opened 3 windows. The Tk window, the "firstWindow", and the "secondWindow". The Tk window held the first image and when that button was clicked it packed the second image into the Tk window

Comment: Have you tried the updated code? It's working fine for me.

Comment: It is very close. I should be able to get the second image to show up in the second window. Thanks

Comment: `labelTwo = Label(secondWindow, image=photoTwo).pack()`

It is this line which is crucial.

Comment: Omg I feel like such a noob lol. I skipped right over it thanks alot. Marking question as answered now

Comment: Haha, my bad for not spotting it straight away!

Comment: If I wanted to use this more than once could I? I know I would have to make a new function with it's own name but could I recycle this code in theory?

Answer (score 0):

To get create a more sustainable window creation, use this:

```
from tkinter import *
import time

def openThirdWindow(previouswindow):
    previouswindow.destroy()


    thirdWindow = Tk()
    thirdWindow.title("Third Window")

    photoTwo = PhotoImage(file="freedom.gif")
    labelTwo = Label(thirdWindow, image=photoTwo).pack()

    thirdWindow.mainloop()

def openSecondWindow(previouswindow):
    previouswindow.destroy()


    secondWindow = Tk()
    secondWindow.title("Second Window")

    photoTwo = PhotoImage(file="freedom.gif")
    labelTwo = Label(secondWindow, image=photoTwo).pack()

    closeBttn = Button(secondWindow, text="Close!", command= lambda: openThirdWindow(secondWindow))
    closeBttn.pack()

    secondWindow.mainloop()


def openFirstWindow():
    firstWindow = Tk()


    firstWindow.title("First Window")

    logo = PhotoImage(file="burger.gif")
    w1 = Label(firstWindow, image=logo).pack()

    closeBttn = Button(firstWindow, text="Close!", command= lambda: openSecondWindow(firstWindow))
    closeBttn.pack()

    firstWindow.mainloop()

openFirstWindow()
```

This places the opening of each window in a seperate function, and passes the name of the window through the button presses into the next function. Another method would be setting the window names as global, but this is messy.

The function "lambda:" calls the function, in tkinter you must type this if you want to pass something through a command.

We initiate the whole process first first called "openFirstWindow()"